Oxygen requirement of Eschericia coli
What is a good DO% range for E. coli cultivation (BL21(DE3), recombinant protein expression). 30%? At what point is a culture oxygen-limited, or 'highly aerated'? If DO% is relative to reactor conditions, how can we compared values?

Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on this site and how it works. As usual with these sorts of question, the homework poicly applies - so tell us what you have found in the literature.

Wow, I really mis-typed "policy" there

@bob1 LOL... happens to all of us humans... Just FYI, even after 5 minutes, if no one has responded to your comment, you can simply delete your comment and repost it with your error(s) fixed. (Technically, you can do that even if someone has responded, but that gets confusing.)

@EndAntisemiticHate I am aware of that, just couldn't be bothered retyping.

@bob1 Ah, I thought you were perhaps copy and pasting your comment (or using a script), given it includes a lot of text plus several links.
